# How to add WCF Service reference in ASP.NET Core web API 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, wcf

I try add service reference in my ASP.net Core Web API but the following error happens:

```
Unable to generate deps.json, it may have been already generated.  You can specify the "-d" option 
before the tool name for diagnostic output (for example, "dotnet -d <toolname>": C:\Program 
Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\GenerateDeps\GenerateDeps.proj
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the dotnet-svcutil command to generate the web service reference file:

```
dotnet-svcutil http://contoso.com/SayHello.svc
```

Use this command to install dotnet-svcutil:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-svcutil
```

For more information about dotnet-svcutil, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x).

Comment: i have .wsdl if I put the wsdl does not work

Comment: What bindings are used in your WCF server? Some bindings are not supported in core.